# add a plugin from a library in tailwind

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, nomachine-nx

I am using react, nx, tailwind to create a monorepo with multiple config

What I would like to achieve is

one config for the whole repo
one config per project
one plugin that extend the project config on each lib.

I currently have this :

`root::tailwind.config` (base styles)

```
module.exports = {
  content: [],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        '27313B': '#27313B',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

`project::tailwdind.config` (extends the root and call for a plugin)

```
const { createGlobPatternsForDependencies } = require('@nrwl/react/tailwind');
const { join } = require('path');

module.exports = {
  content: [
    join(__dirname, 'src/**/!(*.stories|*.spec).{ts,tsx,html}'),
    ...createGlobPatternsForDependencies(__dirname),
  ],
  presets: [require(join(__dirname, '../../tailwind.config'))],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [require(join(__dirname, '../../libs//tailwind.plugin'))],
};
```

`lib::tailwind.plugin`

```
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    plugin(
      function ({ matchUtilities, theme }) {
        matchUtilities(
          {
            colors: (value) => ({
              colors: value,
            }),
          },
          { values: theme('colors') }
        );
      },
      {
        theme: {
          extend: {
            colors: {
              F00: '#f00',
            },
          },
        },
      }
    ),
  ],
};
```

Sadly, the plugin never work,

doing
`<div className={'text-27313B'}>asdasd</div>`
show the good color but
`<div className={'text-F00'}>asdasd</div>`
dont

I am configuring it wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

you try this

```
 module.exports = {
      content: [],
      theme: {
        extend: {
          colors: {
            27313B: '#27313B',
          },
        },
      },
      plugins: [],
    };
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: hi, thanks for answer, the problem is not with `27313B` but with `F00` I would like my project to have both the colors. one from main config, one from plugin

Answer (score 0):

ok I copy pasted wrong...

```
module.exports = plugin(
  function ({ matchUtilities, theme }) {
    matchUtilities(
      {
        colors: (value) => ({
          colors: value,
        }),
      },
      { values: theme('colors') }
    );
  },
  {
    theme: {
      extend: {
        colors: {
          F00: '#f00',
        },
      },
    },
  }
);
```

works.

I was exporting a plugin : plugin() instead of just plugin()